# Downloading multiple text file from server, however, the files are not found

Tags: android, download, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to download several text files from a server. They all have similar names (e.g text1.txt, txt2.txt) but different numbers (changing quantities every month). I can't seem to download the files. Java keeps telling me that it is encountering a file not found error/exception. Does anyone know how I can get past this?

The download class.

```
  public class downloadText extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {


                File sourceLocation = new File(targetPath);
                sources = sourceLocation.listFiles();

                Arrays.sort(sources);


                File root = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "aiyo/edition/text/");

                if (dir.exists() == false) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }

                Log.d("param", params[0]);
                URL url = new URL("http://create.aiyomag.com/assets/app_mag/ALYO/9_1342080926/text"); // you can write here any link
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                int contentLength=connection.getContentLength();


                // get file name and file extension


                String fileExtenstion = MimeTypeMap
                        .getFileExtensionFromUrl(params[0]);
                String name = URLUtil.guessFileName(params[0], null,
                        fileExtenstion);
                File file = new File(dir, name);
                Log.d("File in content","The file is "+file.getName());

                /*
                 * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                 */
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                /*
                 * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to
                 * read(-1).
                 */

                int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
                int total = 0;
                byte baf[] = new byte[1024];
                int current = 0;
                while ((current = bis.read(baf)) != -1) {

                    total += current;
                    // publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) /
                    // lenghtOfFile));
                    mProgressDialog.setProgress(((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    fos.write(baf, 0, current);
                }

                // close every file stream
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                is.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
            }
           return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          //  if (fileInteger == max) {
          //      dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
          //      return;
          //  }


            Log.d("post execute", "i::" + fileInteger);
          //  fileInteger++;
            // publishProgress("" + (int) ((fileInteger * 100) / max));
        //    mProgressDialog.setSecondaryProgress(((fileInteger * 100) / max));
            String link = txturl;

            downloadText = new downloadText();
            downloadText.execute(link);
        }
```

The main.

```
    btn_txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.text);

    btn_txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String link;
            link = txturl+fileInteger+".txt";

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    max = (totalFile(pageNum) - 1);
                    text.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            text.setText("" + max);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

            downloadText = new downloadText();
            downloadText.execute(link);         
        }

        });
```

Comment: Well, I do get a 403 error when I visit that link...

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a 403 error when I access that link. It means the page can be reached, but the server is forbidding me from accessing it. That's why no files are being downloaded and hence the resource not found error.

If you run the server yourself, then you can look into the backend code and server configurations to see why this is happening. Otherwise you need to contact the administrator of the server and request permission to access the page.

Once you get the required permission, you can download a list of files by either

1. passing an array of url's to your doInBackground method(one for each file) or
2. the better option would be to ask the admin to create a script to zip the files on the server and keep it at a specified url. Then you can download the zip file and extract it in your app. This is much better than downloading files one by one since it saves the number of requests, bandwidth and the number of error possibilities.

example code to zip files in php:

```
<?php

// Adding files to a .zip file, no zip file exists it creates a new ZIP file

// increase script timeout value
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5000);

// create object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

// open archive 
if ($zip->open('my-archive.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die ("Could not open archive");
}

// initialize an iterator
// pass it the directory to be processed
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("themes/"));

// iterate over the directory
// add each file found to the archive
foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
    $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
}

// close and save archive
$zip->close();
echo "Archive created successfully.";
?>
```

Downloading zip file tutorial:
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521

Unzip file tutorial:
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29

Comment: I've already asked her and she said that i could only access the files if i know the name. The name of the txt files is 1,txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and so on. 


It should be something like this http://create.aiyomag.com/assets/app_mag/ALYO/9_1342080926/text/1.txt

How do I download this files without knowing the exact range of the file?

Comment: Unless the server has some sort of directory index enabled, you can't. If you know they are in sequence (starts at 1 and goes to X), you could keep going. Once you hit X+1 you'll get a 403 (or 404) and you can stop. I suggest looking at some tutorials on general HTTP transfer.

Comment: irbull I've just got past on how to know the range of the file. Now I need to know how to download the whole list. Any ideas?